# Consolidating array accesses

Tags: lua

Is there a better or easier way of doing this?

```
if array[1] and array[2] and array[3] and array[4] and array[5] == false then

    --somthing

end
```

I have a lot of arrays to check and was wondering if there is a way to work with arrays where you can do something like `array[1-6]` or `[1,6]` or something. Can't seem to find anything online.

Comment: The code in the title is different than what you put in the text. Which one you you want to "shrink"?

Comment: the one in text... But it doesnt seem to be possible..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function like this:

```
function checktruth(t, i, e)
    local r = true
    for j = i, e do
        r = r and t[j]
    end
    return r
end
```

And then call:

```
if checktruth(array, 1, 4) and not array[5] then
```

As you can see, it can not handle the last part (not array[5]), but you can modify it (not without making it more verbose).

Comment: the arrays to check is not always in numbers right after each other, but this inspired me to find a solution :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of the lua syntax but something like

```
arrayAllFalse=TRUE;
for element in array
  if (element) then 
  arrayAllFalse=FALSE
  end

if (arrayALLFalse) then
    --something
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If the amount is known (5 elements, etc) then I'd use [unpack](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-unpack) (table.unpack in Lua 5.2), especially if your last condition is "== false" instead of "true", like the rest:

```
local t1,t2,t3,t4,t5 = unpack(array)

if t1 and t2 and t3 and t4 and not t5 then
  ...
end
```

Comment: this wont shrink the amount of text written.

Comment: On each line, it does. And it's also clearer, especially if you give the variables a good name.

Answer (score 1):

If you'resure you'll never have strings as keys formatted as "number-number" in the table, you could give this a metamethod twist:

```
tab={'a','b','c','d','e'}
mt={ __index=function(t,k)
    if type(k)=="string" then
        from,to=k:match("(%d+)-(%d+)")
        res={}
        print(from,to)
        for i = tonumber(from),tonumber(to) do
             print("",i-from+1)
             res[i-from+1]=t[tonumber(i)]
        end
        return res
    end
end}
setmetatable(tab,mt)
print(unpack(tab["1-3"]))
```